# Resetting $PATH in OS X 10.8

Tags: macos, unix, path, alias

I was trying to install `jhbuild` earlier as part of a GTK+ install, and ran the command
`alias jhbuild="PATH=gtk-prefix/bin:$PATH jhbuild"`. Since then, I haven't been able to access many important services (including Homebrew and MacPorts), since, obviously, the `$PATH` variable has been changed.

Here's the problem: when I try to reset the `$PATH` variable to the default one (found by running `echo $PATH` on my other machine, also running OS X 10.8, whose `$PATH` hasn't been modified), I get this error message:

```
-bash: alias: `/Users/[my user name]/anaconda/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/X11/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/usr/local/MacGPG2/bin:/usr/texbin': invalid alias name
```

What can be done to undo the modified `$PATH` alias?

EDIT: Running `$PATH` (*not* `echo $PATH`) on the machine presenting the issue returns

```
/Users/[my user name]/anaconda/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/X11/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/usr/local/MacGPG2/bin:/usr/texbin: No such file or directory
```

EDIT: Running `echo $PATH` gives

```
/Users/[my user name]/anaconda/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/X11/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/usr/local/MacGPG2/bin:/usr/texbin
```

Which gives the same thing as running `$PATH`, but without the error message.

EDIT: My `~/.bash_profile` file:

```
# added by Anaconda 1.5.1 installer
export PATH="/Users/[my user name]/anaconda/bin:$PATH"
```

And my `~/.profile` file:

```
# MacPorts Installer addition on 2013-03-12_at_12:06:00: adding an appropriate PATH variable for use with MacPorts.
export PATH=/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:$PATH
# Finished adapting your PATH environment variable for use with MacPorts.


##
# Your previous /Users/[my user name]/.profile file was backed up as /Users/[my user name]/.profile.macports-saved_2013-03-21_at_16:08:32
##

# MacPorts Installer addition on 2013-03-21_at_16:08:32: adding an appropriate PATH variable for use with MacPorts.
export PATH=/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:$PATH
# Finished adapting your PATH environment variable for use with MacPorts.


##
# Your previous /Users/[my user name]/.profile file was backed up as /Users/[my user name]/.profile.macports-saved_2013-03-21_at_16:14:16
##

# MacPorts Installer addition on 2013-03-21_at_16:14:16: adding an appropriate PATH variable for use with MacPorts.
export PATH=/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:$PATH
# Finished adapting your PATH environment variable for use with MacPorts.
```

I'm not sure where to add `/opt/local/bin` as suggested by Celada.

Comment: "Running `$PATH`" makes no sense. `$PATH` contains a colon-separated list of directories. You can't treat that as a command and run it.

Comment: What reasons can there be for `bash`'s inability to access `brew`, `macports`, and a number of other applications?

Comment: Well, as for Macports, I notice that `/opt/local/bin` is not in your `$PATH` which is probably should be. `brew`, I'm not familiar with. But if you changed your `$PATH`, you did it by some other means than simply defining a harmless alias (which doesn't even live longer than the shell it was defined in). Check if you changed `~/.profile` or `~/.bash_profile` or similar files, for example.

Comment: I've found both `~/.profile` and `~/.bash_profile`, but they show conflicting values for `$PATH`.

Comment: Well, I would say that setting `$PATH` in both `~/.profile` and `~/.bash_profile` is poor form, but the bash manpage mentions "~/.bash_profile, ~/.bash_login, and ~/.profile, in that order", so at least you know which one runs latest and therefore overrides changes made in the others.

Comment: If both ~/.profile and ~/.bash_profile exist, bash will run ~/.bash_profile and ignore ~/.profile. On the other hand, if you run a non-bash shell it'll do the reverse. Main result: lots of confusion. My recommendation would be to move the Anaconda content to ~/.profile and remove ~/.bash_profile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The alias you present:

```
alias jhbuild="PATH=gtk-prefix/bin:$PATH jhbuild"
```

doesn't change the default `$PATH`. In fact, it doesn't even change the `$PATH` for the current shell. It changes the `$PATH` *only* for the run of the `jhbuild` command. Theres is no "restoring" that you should have to be doing. Even if you had changed the `$PATH` for the current shell, closing the shell in which you had done that would have sufficed to get rid of the change.

Based on the very odd error message you receive when trying to set the `$PATH` to something else, I suspect that the alias you defined earlier is somehow not the alias you thought you defined (a quoting problem?). I can't imagine what it might have been though. I can't imagine what would cause the error message when you are trying to reset the `$PATH` to mention aliases in any way at all.

I suggest you type `alias` alone without arguments to see what aliases are actually defined. That might give you a clue.

Comment: The only defined alias is `alias jhbuild='PATH=gtk-prefix/bin:/Users/[my user name]/anaconda/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/X11/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/usr/local/MacGPG2/bin:/usr/texbin jhbuild'`. Is there any other reason why typing `brew` or `port` would return `command not found` by `bash`?

Comment: The existence of that alias would have absolutely no effect on `brew` or `port`.

Comment: I ran `$PATH` and posted the result in the main question.